# How should I use tf.scan to implement this recurrence relation?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to implement the following function in Tensorflow.

The input is a tensor `x` of shape `(n, 1)`

The output is a tensor `y` of shape `(n, 1)`.

I fix a tensor `a` of shape `(2, 1)`.

Then I want to calculate `y` by the following formula.

```
y[0] = x[0]
y[1] = x[1] - a[0] * x[0]
y[2] = x[2] - a[0] * x[1] - a[1] * x[0]
... 
y[i] = x[i] - a[0] * x[i - 1] - a[1] * x[i - 2]
```

I would like the entries of `a` to be trainable.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

EDIT:  I am attempting a solution that might look like this:

```
elems = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0])

init = (np.array([0, 0]), 0)

# a = initialize
# y = elems[0]

# test first step
# print((np.array([a[0][1], a[1]]), a[0][0] + a[0][1] + y))

a1 = tf.Variable(-1)
a2 = tf.Variable(-1)

def f(x, y):
    return (tf.stack([x[0][1], x[1]], 0), y - a1 * x[0][1] - a2 * x[0][1])

c = tf.scan(f, elems, initializer=init)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(c))
```

Where `elems` is the input `x` and the last column of `c` should be `y`.  It doesn't work yet, the answer should be

`1     1     3     4     8    13    22    35    58    93`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem.

```
elems = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0])

init = (np.array([0, 0]), 0)

a1 = tf.Variable(-1)
a2 = tf.Variable(-1)

def f(x, y):
    return (tf.stack([x[0][1], x[1]], 0), y - a2 * x[0][1] - a1 * x[1])
    
c = tf.scan(f, elems, initializer=init)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(c))
```

To explain how tf.scan works in this case, you can see the following sample MATLAB code for the fibonnaci sequence.

```
% tensor to feed in helper information at each step
elems = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; 

% initialize memory
initialize = [0, 1]; 

% define the function f(current_memory, current_element) = next_memory
f = @(a, y) [a(2), a(1) + a(2)];  
% in this case, the element is not used, but in the previous example, it is

% memory storage tensor (Fib result is second column)
x = zeros(length(elems), length(initialize)); 

% run tf.scan
x(1, :) = f(initialize, elems(1));
for i = 2:length(elems)
    x(i, :) = f(x(i - 1, :), elems(i));
end
```

The function f(a, y) takes two arguments, a: a "memory" tensor, and y: the current entry of the elems tensor.  In this Fibonacci case, f is ignoring the elems tensor, but in the example above, it uses it.

Comment: May I ask what does `tf.scan` do here?